# Why do I need a tool like browserify?

Tags: javascript, gulp, browserify

I have an angularjs project with gulp configuration.

In my gulpfile.js I merge all my code to a bundle.js file. I also add 3rd party library code there, minify it and it works fine. I don't understand what it will improve. I read a lot of articles, but couldn't find anything to make me understand. All it writes is how it is better than requirejs. I don't even use requirejs.

Comment: May I ask what exactly are you using right now to create that bundle?

Comment: @E_net4 I use gulp-concat

Comment: Are you just using the global scope to keep plain JavaScript objects accessible from everywhere else in your code base? This information should really be in the question.

Comment: Browserify bundles CommonJS modules, which provide better encapsulation. You may wish to read more about using different module systems [here](https://www.airpair.com/javascript/posts/the-mind-boggling-universe-of-javascript-modules).

Answer (score 1):

Browserify is a particular way to merge all your code. If you're already doing so and it works well for you, then you don't need it.

Once your project grows bigger, you're probably going to need a better way to structure your code into modules. That's where browserify helps you a lot. It also makes it easy to use many of the modules you find on `npm`.